# Custom delay between keyDown and keyUp - selenium.webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automated-tests

I'm trying to make bot for website, that detects bots by comparing times between keyUp and keyDown, found this in the source code of the website. So while typing by using webdriver [send_keys()](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/keyboard/#sendkeys) all the times are too small(1ms)/similar and I get blocked. The text that I need to type is different every time I log into the website.

My current code, that gets me blocked:

```py
import time
import random 

text = "Some text"
for l in text:
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.12, 0.4))
    element.send_keys(l)
```

For example i need to type letter "s", so i do send_keys("s") and from my understanding of selenium this under the hood produces [keyDown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) and [keyUp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event) event to simulate pressing and releasing of key "s". And between them is where i need to put that delay, but i cant find way to do so.
Some random human-like delay between [keyUp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event) and [keyDown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) could trick the bot detection. Feel free to leave any idea on how to workaround this bot-detection.
Thanks for help in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty tricky problem. The only way I can think to do it is use `ActionChains`, specifically the keyUp and keyDown functions. In the Selenium documentation, it says that keyup and keydown are only for "modifier" keys (`CTRL`, `ENTER`, `SHIFT`, etc). But I think we can use them for regular alphanumeric characters as well. I went through a lot of Selenium source code, and ultimately found that what is passed in to `send_keys()`, `key_up()`, and `key_down()` is handled as a `KeyInput`, a class defined in [this file from the selenium python bindings](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/b287e73ce2b148a2eff82539b9860a6237722c02/py/selenium/webdriver/common/actions/key_input.py#L24). Thankfully that class seems perfectly happy to accept any key so hopefully we can proceed using `key_up('a')` and the like.

So now, how to accomplish your actual goal, of having a delay between all `key_up` and `key_down`, and then another delay before the next key press. I'm sure you'll want to play with the range for randomizing the wait time, for now I just copied what you did.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
import random 

text = "Some text"
for l in text:
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.key_down(l).pause(random.uniform(0.12, 0.4)).key_up(l).perform()
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.12, 0.4))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

for i in "somestring":
    time.sleep(1)
    element.send_keys(i)
```

This creates delay of 1 sec between each character,

Comment: Thanks for answer, but thats not what im trying to achieve. For example i need to type letter "s", so i do  `send_keys("s")` and from my understanding of selenium this under the hood produces [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) and [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keyup_event) event to simulate pressing and releasing of key "s". And between them is where i need to put that delay, but i cant find way to do so.